# Event Listener and AJAX asynchronous function variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

I got a question, probably very simple, but whatever. When registering an event listener inside an asynchronous function, I would believe that all values within that function would be non-existing when the function has run it's course.

However, an event listener, as displayed below in the code can still access the variable `values`, how is that? Is the variable saved within the event listener somehow?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "/whatever",
    success: function(data) {
        var values = ["Some Values", "Inside this Object"];

        $("#id :checkbox").click(function() { 
            var allValues = [];

            $('#id3 :checked').each(function() {
                allValues.push($(this).val());
            });

            $("#id2").val(allValues);

            callMe.init(values,allValues);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The JavaScript Garden doesn't give an explicit answer, but does use it as a solution to `this` references: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this (Common Pitfalls, 2nd snippet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of closures. A function "closes over" all variables in its lexical scope, which is to say that it retains access to them once the function in which it was defined has returned.

In your specific example, `values` is in scope when the function given to `click` is defined, so it will remain accessible even once `success` completes.

You'll find a lot more information here:

- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @Anders - It's accessible to any function defined in `success`. In your example, the function given to `click` is the only function that's still "alive" after the call to `success` so it's the only function that retains access. However, imagine you were to define another function inside `success` and then `return` it from `success`. You'd be able to call that function later and it would have access to `values`.

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery $ sign is in the global scope. Anything can reference it. You are reaching the form checkbox values through $.

Comment: @user344215 - That's not what he asked. He's wondering why the inner function can still access `values` once `success` has returned.

Comment: Oh, I thought he was referring to the form values, not the local scope "values" in success. I understand the question now as "How can the anonymous function bound to the click event of $("#id :checkbox") access the array named values created in my $.ajax success event?"